# RabbitMQ publisher confirms with topic exchange - BasicAcks only fires once the first time

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, message-ack

Using a *topic* exchange, I would like to have a publish/subscribe messaging pattern with the following features:

1. Have "*publisher confirms*" implemented.
2. Have the **consumer acknowledge** each message as well once it has processed it.
3. Use *routing keys* to route messages to one or more consumers.
4. Have **persistent** consumer queues so if the consumer application is down temporarily, it can pick up messages from its queue when it comes back up.

So I have created 2 console applications (Send and Receive) to test the above.

**Send**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(" Type [exit] to exit.");

        Publisher publisher = new Publisher();

        do
        {
            var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userInput == "exit")
            {
                break;
            }


            publisher.SendMessageToBroker("localhost", "main", "user.update", userInput);

        } while (true);
    }
```

**Publisher**

```
public class Publisher
{
    const string ExchangeType = "topic";

    Dictionary<ulong, string> unConfirmedMessageTags = new Dictionary<ulong, string>();

    public void SendMessageToBroker(string host, string exchangeName, string routingKey, string message)
    {

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = host };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {                
            channel.BasicAcks += (sender, ea) => OnBasicAcks(ea.Multiple, ea.DeliveryTag);
            channel.BasicNacks += (sender, ea) => OnBasicNacks(ea.Multiple, ea.DeliveryTag);

            channel.ConfirmSelect();

            channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, ExchangeType);

            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            properties.Persistent = true;

            unConfirmedMessageTags.TryAdd(channel.NextPublishSeqNo, message);

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: exchangeName,
                routingKey: routingKey,
                basicProperties: properties,
                body: body);

            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        }
    }

    private void OnBasicNacks(bool multiple, ulong deliveryTag)
    {
        if (multiple)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Messages with delivery tag LESS THAN {0} have been LOST and must be resent.", deliveryTag);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message with delivery tag {0} has been LOST and must be resent.", deliveryTag);
        }
    }

    private void OnBasicAcks(bool multiple, ulong deliveryTag)
    {
        if (multiple)
        {
            var confirmed = unConfirmedMessageTags.Where(k => k.Key <= deliveryTag);
            foreach (var entry in confirmed)
            {
                unConfirmedMessageTags.Remove(entry.Key);
                Console.WriteLine("Message with delivery tag {0} has been confirmed and deleted.", entry.Key);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            unConfirmedMessageTags.Remove(deliveryTag);
            Console.WriteLine("Message with delivery tag {0} has been confirmed and deleted.", deliveryTag);
        }

    }
}
```

}

**Receive**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string ExchangeName = "main";
        const string QueueName = "q1";
        const string ExchangeType = "topic";
        const string RoutingKey = "user.update";

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare(ExchangeName, ExchangeType);

            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: QueueName, 
                durable: true, 
                autoDelete: false, 
                exclusive: false, 
                arguments: null);

            channel.QueueBind(QueueName, ExchangeName, RoutingKey);

            //channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            consumer.Received += (model, ea) => Basic_Ack(channel, ea.DeliveryTag, ea.Body);

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: QueueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }            
    }

    private static void Basic_Ack(IModel channel, ulong deliveryTag, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> body)
    {            
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);            

        channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: deliveryTag, multiple: false);

        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Processed {0}", message);
    }
}
```

The problem is the **OnBasicAcks** in my *Send* program only gets called once for the first message.

[image]

Comment: Update: If I unbind the consumer queue from the exchange, then I successfully receive BasicAcks (publisher confirmation) for every message I send. But as soon as I bind a consumer queue, only the first message gets acknowledged by the broker to the publisher and all subsequent messages do not receive acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else out there who may hit this issue, I was opening a connection and channel (virtual connection) for every publish which is [discouraged](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html):

"Connections are **meant to be long-lived**. Opening a connection for every operation (e.g. publishing a message) would be very inefficient and is **highly discouraged**."

Also see [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-seven-dotnet.html):

"Publisher confirms are enabled at the channel level with the ConfirmSelect method... This method must be called on every channel that you expect to use publisher confirms. Confirms should be enabled just once, not for every message published."

Switching to using a long-lived connection solved the issue for me.